# Name conflicts with _FilterDatabase

Tags: excel, powershell, autofilter

I'm getting a "Name conflicts" dialog box after I try to run my Powershell script the second time on the same file. I know that this error has something to do with me autofiltering the file. If I never use autofiter, then the dialog box won't show. What am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open("testtabelle1.xlsx")
Trap {"Worksheet problems..."} $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1) | Out-Null

$from = ">0"
$to = "<2"

$workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").AutoFilter(1, $from, 1, $to) > $null

#Reset Selection and close file
#$workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select() | Out-Null
$workbook.Save()
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
```

Comment: `$excel.Range("D:D").AutoFilter(1, $from, 1, $to) > $null` Not worked with powershell but shouldn't this be `$SomeWorksheet.Range("D:D").AutoFilter(1, $from, 1, $to) > $null`

Comment: It doesn't matter. I've updated the question with a different approach leading to the same problem...

Comment: See if this helps? Run the code from VBA Editor in Excel in `testtabelle1.xlsx` and then save the file http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exceldev/thread/546c7506-7146-45b6-873e-b3793df2979b

Comment: Do you get the error if before execute script for 2nd time you close and reopen powershell?

Comment: @C.B. Yes, I still get the error...

Comment: @SiddharthRout It works partly. I'm not allowed to remove the filter. What I'm trying however, is to remove the _FilterDatbase Name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to delete the Name "_FilterDatabase", because this name is only allowed once.

The Names object is a hastable. Therefore you Need to delete the key like this:

`$workbook.Names.Item("_FilterDatabase").Delete()`

Comment: Sorry to bring this one up again but i am currently experiencing the same problem as OP. Where would one call this? I get the popup when calling the `$excel.Workbooks.Open()` method so `$workbook` does not even exist until that point. Also i am not doing any filtering in my script so i have no clue why this occurs

Answer (score 0):

Also it might be useful to do something like this after `$workbook.Names.Item("_FilterDatabase").Delete()`:

```
$Items_FD = $workbook.Names | ?{ $_.Name -match "_FilterDatabase" }
$Items_FD | %{
  try{
    $_.Delete() | Out-Null
  }
  catch{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub IdentifyNames()

Dim defName As Name

With ThisWorkbook 'Entire workbook
  For Each defName In .Names
  If Right(defName.Name, 14) = "FilterDatabase" Then defName.delete
  'Debug.Print defName.Name
  Next
End With

End Sub
```

comment part lists defined names